# AngularJS UI Bootstrap Typeahead not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm building a small search app using Elasticsearch and AngularJS. I'm using AngularJS UI bootstrap typeahead to implement autocomplete and I'm using ES's `edge_n_grams` and `highlight object` to 1) generate the suggestions and 2) highlight the suggestions, respectively. ES highlight object wraps the suggestions in `HTML <em></em>` tags... which *seems* to be causing some issues with how I have things setup.

1) When I press Enter key instead of clicking on the search button - all that happens is the search terms are displayed wrapped in the `<em></em>` tags AND no search is performed... `<em>search terms</em>`

2) When I select a suggestion with the mouse, same thing happens.

The only time search performs is when I type a query in and click the search button...

Here is the search form that I'm using, I have ng-submit="search()" on the form element and on the button, not sure where I'm going wrong......?

```
<form name="q" ng-submit="search()" class="navbar-form" id="results-search" role="search">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="q" ng-model="searchTerms" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="{{ searchTerms }}" id="search-input" uib-typeahead="query for query in getSuggestions($viewValue)" typeahead-on-select="search($item)">

      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" ng-submit="search()" class="btn btn-primary btn-md"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i></button>
        </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Am I doing something wrong with the UI Bootstrap Typeahead?

**More clarification**
So basically what I'm asking is how do I get the  tags stripped from the suggestions, on selection and for searching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar kind of example already asked in Stackoverflow: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321439/angular-ui-bootstrap-show-dropdown-on-typeahead-no-results)

Comment: I'm getting suggestions... drop displays just fine, its more of a problem with formatting of the query properly - stripping the <em></em> tags from the suggestions

Comment: Use console.log and try to find what happens when click Enter key and selecting the dropdown in mouse and what happens when you click the search button.

Comment: If you could put your code in plunker it will be really easy to see your code and analyse it.